# mvc route ignored but correct in route debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have some jquery posting to a url but comes up as 404

```
                createOrder: function () {
                return fetch('/paypalcreate', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        data: contactjson,
                        cartsessionid: CartSessionId
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }).then(function (res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function (data) {
                    orderId = data.d.Result.orderID;
                    return orderId;
                });
```

But digging into the code - If I check with route bugger it shows what rules and routes should handle it

[image: route debugger]

and here is my route:

[image: route config]

and my controller is as below:

[image: controller]

So really confused as to why its coming up as 404 as the route debugger shows the route is specified correctly and the controller looks correct, yet nothing is working

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, changed the controller call and removed 'Public Shared'

Now just reads:

Async Function PayPalCreate(ByVal data As String, ByVal cartsessionid As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Object)

controller now picks up witht he route and respinds